# Nested templates in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates

I want to template one function for code reuse and specialization.

The function signature is something along the lines `int DoStuff(FooBar &a);` where FooBar is `Foo<BarX>`, that is, an instance of template that I cannot typedef beforehand.

I tried to do `template <class T> int DoStuff(Foo<T> &a);` and `template <class T> int DoStuff(T &a);`, but I'm getting the regular cryptic linker errors that doesn't help even a little bit.

Couldn't find the tutorials on such subject too, found only for simplified template usage.

The code would be called like:

```
Foo<Bar1> var1;
int res1 = DoStuff(var1);
Foo<Bar2> var2;
int res2 = DoStuff(var2);
etc.
```

Am I trying to do something impossible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you suggested: `template <class T> int DoStuff(Foo<T> &a);` should work.
Note that as with templated structs/classes, the code for the function must be visible where the function is used (i.e., the code for the function must typically be in a header).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not having any issue with this. Here is an example, compilable program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

template<typename T> class Foo{};
class Bar1{};
class Bar2{};

template<typename T> int DoStuff(Foo<T>& ref) { return rand(); }

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Foo<Bar1> var1;
    int res1 = DoStuff(var1);
    std::cout << "res1 = " << res1 << std::endl;

    Foo<Bar2> var2;
    int res2 = DoStuff(var2);
    std::cout << "res2 = " << res2 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

What, exactly, are you trying to accomplish? I suspect your errors may be a result of providing too many overloads such that there are multiple valid overloads, and therefore it is ambiguous. Are you providing both an overload for `DoStuff(Foo&)` as well as for `DoStuff(T&)`? Try using just one.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's perfectly possible with template specialization.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Foo {};

template <typename T>
void DoStuff(const T& val)
{
    std::cout << val << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void DoStuff(const Foo<T>& val)
{
    std::cout << "Sorry, I can not print Foos" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    Foo<int> b;
    DoStuff(b);
    DoStuff(5);
}
```

Output:

```
Sorry, I can not print Foos
5
```

If you want it to work only for Foo instantiations, define `DoStuff` like this:

```
template <typename T>
void DoStuff(const T& val);

template <typename T>
void DoStuff(const Foo<T>& val)
{
    std::cout << "Foosome argument" << std::endl;
}
```

Furthermore, you can blacklist, whitelist or specialize any Foo instantiation.